# Set a variable from Query A and Parse to Query B

Tags: postgresql, jasper-reports

An application is creating a new table based on the value of a column.
eg. a user in is the 'users' table with list_id = 2.  So there is a corresponding table more_data_2 I need to join - to complete the query.

How do I begin to build a dynamic query like the concept below please in PostgreSQL 10:

```
SET var_user = ('John Smith')
SET var_list_id = (select list_id from users
inner join user_list on users.user_list_id = user_list.id 
where name = (var_user)) #value is 2
    select user_name,uuid,more_data_uuid,more_data_column_1,more_data_column_2
    from users
    inner join more_data_(var_list_id) on users.uuid = more_data_uuid
    where user_name = (var_user);
```

Which would become

```
SET var_user = ('John Smith')
SET var_list_id = (select list_id from users
inner join user_list on users.user_list_id = user_list.id 
where name = 'John Smith') #value is 2
    select user_name,uuid,more_data_uuid,more_data_column_1,more_data_column_2
    from users
    inner join more_data_2 on users.uuid = more_data_uuid
    where user_name = 'John Smith';
```

To Display

| user_name | uuid | more_data_uuid | more_data_column_1 | more_data_column_2 | more_data_column_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | 123-456 | 123-456 | address | phone | postcode |

Comment: Where/how are you running this script? What kind of "variables" do you expect? If this is some application running a query, you'd normally just use a parameterised query.

Comment: I need to run an SQL query like this in Jasper soft. It will end up being a report.

Comment: `inner join more_data_2` actually can't be done using parameterised queries, you'll need dynamic SQL for that. I've never worked with Jasper soft, either you can write (java?) code there to handle this, or you'll need to define a pl/pgsql function to do this.

Comment: You can pass the parameter "var_user" to the report with value "John Smith". Then you run the first query and the result will be in a Field. You put a List or subreport in detail band, passing the field as parameter. In the subdataset query of the list or the query of the subreport you can create a dynamic query using the parameter.